# batch rename multiple mp3's stripping leading digits

Tags: zsh, batch-rename

Hi could anyone help me? I'm trying to strip leading digits from multiple mp3 files so
`01 some_file.mp3` would become `some_file.mp3`.

If any one could show me how to do it with `zmv` that would be great, thanks.

Comment: if your using zsh this should work. "zmv '[0-9]## #(*.mp3)' '$1'"

Comment: `zmv` isn't a default bash utility, did you mean to ask about `zsh`?

Answer (score 3):

This solution relies on Bash [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) with substitution.

```
# Generate some dummy files for this demonstration
for i in {0..2}{0..9} ; do touch "$i some_file$i.mp3" ; done

# Rename, stripping two leading digits and a space
for i in [0-9][0-9]" "*.mp3 ; do mv "$i" "${i/[0-9][0-9] /}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use extended pattern matching:

```
shopt -s extglob
for F +([[:digit:]])*([[:blank:]])*.mp3; do
    mv -v -- "$F" "${F##+([[:digit:]])*([[:blank:]])}"
done
```

Or recursive:

```
shopt -s extglob

function remove_leading_digits {
    local A B
    for A; do
        B=${1##+([[:digit:]])*([[:blank:]])}
        [[ $A != "$B" ]] && mv -v -- "$A" "$B"
    done
}

readarray -t FILES < <(exec find your_dir -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]*.mp3')
remove_leading_digits "${FILES[@]}"
```

You can save the function to work generally for a script:

```
#!/bin/ash

shopt -s extglob

function remove_leading_digits {
    local A B
    for A; do
        B=${1##+([[:digit:]])*([[:blank:]])}
        [[ $A != "$B" ]] && mv -v -- "$A" "$B"
    done
}

remove_leading_digits "$@"
```

And run it with

```
bash script.sh files
```

Like

```
shopt -s extglob
bash script.sh +([[:digit:]])*.mp3
```

Or just

```
bash script *.mp3  ## Still safe but slower.
```